# Как можно реализовать анимацию?

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Каким способом возможно реализовать анимацию приложенную ниже на JavaScript?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="lang-wrap">
                            <div class="lang">
                                <button class="lang__btn" data-toggle="dropdown">Eng</button>
                                <div class="lang__body">
                                    <a href="" class="lang__item">Rus</a>
                                    <a href=""class="lang__item">Eng</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Можно, допустим, наложить две картинки друг на друга и уменьшать ширину верхней. Блоку с картинкой задать `overflow: hidden`

Comment: есть такой скрипт after/before вот как раз он там поможет

Comment: @MaximLensky Можно немного подробнее?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dBEYwY  смотри - принцип один и тот же

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот css вариант

```css
#lang {
  display: none;
}
#lang:checked ~ .rus,   
#lang:not(:checked) ~ .eng {
  width: 0px;
}
label[for="lang"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 84px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: arial;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
.eng {
  direction: rtl;
  border-left: solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id="lang" type='checkbox'>
<label for="lang" class="rus">RUS</label><label for="lang" class="eng">ENG</label>
```

Comment: Еще появился вопрос, а как сделать чтобы линия появлялась сначала не справа а слева(методом тыка не разобрался что за это отвечает).

Comment: @ДмитрийНиколаевич `#lang:checked ~ .eng,   
#lang:not(:checked) ~ .rus`